# MemoryError when using numpy.save

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'm following Sentdex's Python plays GTA V, where he wrote a code to create self-driving cars in the game using a neural network.  I attempted to directly follow what he did, but when it came time to collect the training data I kept getting a MemoryError after a few minutes on saving the code.  I managed to collect a decent amount of data by saving to multiple files, but I would like to combine these files.  When I run the code to combine the files, I get the same MemoryError when I use numpy.save.
    I have 16 GB of RAM, about 10 of which are free and the total file size is roughly 500 MB.  I'm using PyCharm as my IDE.

Saving to multiple files then combining them was my initial solution, but it results in the same error.
I attempted to save as an HDF5 file, but got a different error.  I honestly didn't put much effort into this yet, but I'd be open to using it as a solution if necessary.
I also tried combining the data into one array before balancing it in the next step, but it only used one of the files (the array was 10,000x5, which is the size of each file).
I checked memory usage while running the code and it was only using 523 MB before it crashed while saving.
I also tried setting allow_pickle=True for the line where I save the file.

I used this to create an array of all of the data from each file and it seems to work fine.

```
import os
import psutil
import h5py

file_name = 'new_training_data.npy'
new_file = []
file_count = 1

while os.path.isfile(file_name):
    new_data = list(np.load(file_name, allow_pickle=True))
    new_file.append(new_data)

    file_name = 'new_training_data' + str(file_count) + '.npy'
    file_count += 1
```

I used this to check memory usage.

```
    # process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    # print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

This is the line giving me problems.

```
np.save('appended_training_data.npy', new_file)
```

This is where I attempted to save as an HDF5 file.

```
# hf = h5py.File('appended_training_data.h5', 'w')
# hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=new_data)
# hf.close()
```

Here's the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/PyGTA/Combine _training_data.py", line 19, in <module>
    np.save('appended_training_data.npy', new_file)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in save
  File "C:\Users\Brian\PycharmProjects\PyGTA\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 542, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\PycharmProjects\PyGTA\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 659, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=3, **pickle_kwargs)
MemoryError
```

Here's the error when I tried saving as HDF5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brian/PycharmProjects/PyGTA/Combine _training_data.py", line 23, in <module>
    hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=new_data)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\PycharmProjects\PyGTA\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 136, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\PycharmProjects\PyGTA\venv\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 118, in make_new_dset
    tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1634, in h5py.h5t.py_create
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1656, in h5py.h5t.py_create
  File "h5py\h5t.pyx", line 1711, in h5py.h5t.py_create
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

edit: I changed the while loop to this to have a consistent np data structure

```
while os.path.isfile(file_name):
    new_data = np.mat(np.load(file_name, allow_pickle=True))

    if len(new_file) == 0:
        new_file = new_data
    else:
        new_file = np.concatenate((new_file, new_data), axis=0)

    file_name = 'new_training_data' + str(file_count) + '.npy'
    file_count += 1
```

Final edit:  I solved this by using Spyder instead of PyCharm.  If someone can shed some light on why it solved the problem, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `new_data` is a object dtype array - an array with a mix of array elements.  `h5py` can't save that.  You have to save each array in its own dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fact that you store everything in a python list is weird to me.
I would try to concat everything in a np.mat then save it with np:
https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays
Do not hybrid np and python data structures unless you know you are lazy.
If your RAM does not bump more than 500MB then size is not an issue, at all.
I used to play with Gigs of data, numpy didn't bulge, my kernel used to crash before Numpy reported an Error when Numpy used to try to unpack 16+GB data overloading my RAM.
Good luck

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general, so I didn't think of the effects of using different data structures.  Using np.mat and concatenating allows me to combine all of the data properly, so it solved the problem of only one array being used in the next step, but I'm still unable to save.  I might just give up on saving the file and just combine my files into one array in all of my future programs.

Comment: This is the new code       `new_data = np.mat(np.load(file_name, allow_pickle=True))
    
    if len(new_file) == 0:
        new_file = new_data
    else:
        new_file = np.concatenate((new_file, new_data), axis=0)  `

Comment: Keep on this way, I agree with @hpaulj Memory error means you overloaded your memory, but the problem must come from the disparate nature of your data which makes it hard to save. Try your code on a smaller sample set to validate it, then find why it explodes in memory.

Comment: Thank you again, I managed to solve the memory error by using Spyder instead of PyCharm.  Now time to figure out Tensorflow...